# Curvature and torsion of coordinate curve on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, spheres

find the curvature and torsion of a $v=v_0$ (= *constant*) coordinate curve on the sphere 
$x(u,v)= (a.\cos u.\sin v$, $a.\sin u .\sin v $, $a.\cos v$),  $\;0 < u < 2\pi$ , $0 < v < \pi$

I couldn't find how to solve because the two variables $(u,v)$. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: but $v$ has been freeze at $v_0$

Comment: so can I convert it like this? r(t) = (a.cost.sinv, a.sint.sinv, a.cosv) should I do this and solve it in a single variable format?

Comment: being $v$ constant your parametrization should be $(aP\cos u, aP\sin u, aQ)$ where $P=\cos v_0$ and $Q=\sin v_0$ are constants. So the position on the curve depends only on $u$.

Comment: yes it needs to be used as P and Q. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a direct approach. Let us use geographical terms.

$v$ is colatitude (= 90° - latitude) : we have a fixed $z=z_0=a \cos v_0$ ; it means that we are cutting the sphere with a horizontal plane. The result is necessarily a circle. We have what is called a parallel (see remark below); let us check that its projection on the $xOy$ plane is a circle ; indeed it has the  following equation

$$x^2+y^2=a^2 (\sin v_0)^2 \left[(\cos t)^2+(\sin t)^2\right]=(a \sin v_0)^2$$

that of a circle with radius $R=a \sin v_0$.

As a consequence this curve :

- has torsion $0$ (because it is a plane curve),
- for its curvature, the inverse of its radius of curvature : $K=1/R=1/(a \sin v_0)$.

**Remark :** Some parallels are famous : for example the Tropic of Cancer (latitude $\approx 23.5°$, colatitude $66.5°$), the Artic circle (invert the values given just before ; do you know why ?), the Equator...

Comment: a nice approach, thank you so much!